# Make "sidebar template" the default template for new pages

Tags: functions, templates, sidebar, child-theme, theme-twenty-eleven

On ***Twenty Eleven*** or on its child themes the default template for new pages is a template with **no sidebar**. I don't know why this is like this; it seems to me that the designers of Wordpress are still not thinking about CMS functionality in some places.

For example the most obvious place to put a menu in a CMS is the sidebar. But with Twenty Eleven the only way to show a menu in all pages is to explicitly set all the pages to ***"sidebar template"***. I would think it's a design bug, as the only solution so far is to tell everyone to *"don't forget to set the new pages to "sidebar template""*.

I'm sure there must be a single line in `functions.php` which changes the default action but I don't know what that line is. Could you tell me what should I write in `functions.php` to set all new pages to ***"sidebar template"*** when using Twenty Eleven?

*I'm sure that it has been asked before but I really couldn't find it anywhere using the search function.*

Answer (score 1):

just add `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` to `page.php` in your child theme and all pages will have a sidebar. look at `sidebar-page.php` to see where to place it.

Comment: OK, but then I am modifying `page.php`. Isn't there a way to keep it minimalistic for the child theme, thus preserving all future updates to page.php?

Comment: @zsero - you can hook `save_post` and add post meta with key `_wp_page_template` and `sidebar-page.php` as value. or I suppose you can add some javascript to the post edit screen that auto-selects a template.

Comment: This will brake the site's design unless you play around with the CSS and the position of the article.